# Serilog: Can I add a property without adding to the message?

Tags: serilog

I have a WIndows .NET app, and starting to use Serilog.
I initialize this like this:

```
Log.Logger = new LoggerConfiguration()
  .MinimumLevel.Verbose()
.Enrich.With(new ThreadIdEnricher())
.Enrich.WithProperty("BuildId", Guid.NewGuid()) // One Guid per run.
.Enrich.FromLogContext()
.WriteTo.RollingFile(@"C:\QRT\Logs\QRT-LOG.txt", LogEventLevel.Verbose)
.WriteTo.Seq("http://localhost:5341" )
.WriteTo.Console(outputTemplate:"{Source} BLAHBLAH {Message:lj}")
.WriteTo.File(new CompactJsonFormatter(), "C:/QRT/Logs/log.json")
.CreateLogger();
```

And I use it like this:

```
_log = Log.ForContext<GameBase>()
.ForContext("InstrumentID", InstrumentId);
_log.Verbose("This is an order: {orderID} / {order}", order.OrderID, order);
```

I'd like my OrderID to be displayed in the message and I'd like the order object to be included as a property (so that I can access it when I dig into this event in Seq) but I do not want the message itself to contain the object (too big). Is there a way to do this?

Or so I need something like this:

```
using (var __log = _log.PushProperty("order", order)
{
  __log.Verbose ("Hit {orderID}", orderID);
}
```

Seems like a lot of code...

Answer (score 3):

You can add anther `ForContext` to your logger for `order` object the same way you add `InstrumentID` and it will be included as a property

```
_log = Log.ForContext<GameBase>()
    .ForContext("InstrumentID", InstrumentId)
    .ForContext("Order", order, true);

_log.Verbose("This is an order: {orderID}", order.OrderID);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
_log.ForContext("order", order, true).Verbose("Hit {orderID}", orderID);
```

The `true` here tells Serilog to serialized ("destructure") `order` instead of calling its `ToString()` method.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but [there are weird tricks involved](https://github.com/serilog/serilog/issues/1124)

---

eta example:

```
class ScalarValueEnricher : ILogEventEnricher
{
    readonly LogEventProperty _prop;

    public ScalarValueEnricher(string name, object value)
    {
        _prop = new LogEventProperty(name, new ScalarValue(value));
    }

    public void Enrich(LogEvent evt, ILogEventPropertyFactory _)
    {
         evt.AddPropertyIfAbsent(_prop);
    }
}
```

consumed like so:

```
var _log = Log.ForContext<GameBase>()
    .ForContext("InstrumentID", InstrumentId);

_log.ForContext(new ScalarEnricher("order",order)).Verbose("Hit: {orderID}", order.OrderID);
```

You can also of course make temporaries from `_log.ForContext(new ScalarEnricher("order",order))` where that's cleaner/clearer/more efficient.

Comment: Thanks but it seems your code is suggesting using the "Using"... but simple converting to scalar.  So I guess the answer is No... I have to use to Push the property using "Using" if I don't want it in the message.  I wish I could find documentation on Enrichers...

Comment: There is an overload of ForContext that takes an enricher, let me add and examples...